# conda update all messed up pandas-profiling

Tags: pandas, anaconda, conda

I was working fine with using seaborn and pandas-profiling for my pandas dataframe. I then used "coda update --all" and it messed up both seaborn and pandas-profiling. I managed to get seaborn working again but I am unable to get pandas-profiling going again.

I uninstalled it and reinstalled but did not work. I tried to revise back my conda installations but did not work. I tried to use pip install instead of conda install, but did not work. This is what I get when I try these two pandas-profiling commands

```
pp.ProfileReport(train)
AttributeError: module 'pandas_profiling' has no attribute 'ProfileReport'

train.profile_report()
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'
```

However when I do try:

```
import pandas_profiling as pp
```

even though pandas-profiling is not installed it does not complain!?

I also made sure I have only one conda environment. Not sure what to do short of redoing a brand new environment.